Alternatives to pagecolor for working in the dark; pagecolor conflicts with Go To Source
For working in the evenings, I prefer a black page with white text, so that I am exposed to less blue light.
As far as I can tell from searching, the go-to approach is to use:
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

However, the page color package causes TexStudio's "Go to source" functionality to break, which is very inconvenient. For this reason, I am looking for an alternative to the pagecolor package.
Suggestions that do not involve any exotic packages are particularly welcomed, because one of my computers has Windows 11, and installing MikTex updates on Windows 11 causes the "qt platform plugin" initialization error (which breaks MikTex and has no known fix). But I welcome all suggestions, as my non-Windows 11 computers can still update MikTex.
In case it is useful to anyone, a MWE of the pagecolor package breaking "Go to Source" functionality is below.
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{pagecolor} 
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\begin{document}

Hello, here is some text. Right click and select `Go to source.' See, it does not work now. Sad face.

\end{document}


the miktex qt error has been fixed see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1486#issuecomment-2084843465

TeXstudio can automatically invert colours, you don't need any changes in the latex source code.

Right click somewhere on the pdf and select Invert Colors from the context menu (sometimes this needs two clicks, haven't figured out yet why...):

This will give you light text on dark background:

